# Since gcc on mac doesn't support openmp, what can I do to let it support?

Tags: macos, gcc, openmp

At the first,I used the default gcc on my mac.but it does't support openmp.
using "`gcc -v`",I get gcc 4.2.1

So, I used brew to install gcc. When it is done, using the "`gcc -v`",it has no changes.
the brew give tips to me "openmp may not be supported,using "`brew reinstall gcc --without-muli`"??
I don't remember the "muli???" accurately.I try that,but It doesn't help.

So, this is my question: What can I do to make my gcc to support openmp in my macbook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brew will install gcc under a slightly different name to not clobber the existing gcc. The easiest way to check for other gcc's is to type gcc- and then hit the TAB key to see what completions there are. I believe brew's current gcc is 4.9.1, so after installing gcc with brew you should be able to access it with gcc-4.9.

Comment: Glad to hear. If this solved your question, could you mark my answer as correct?