# Compile OpenMP programs with gcc compiler on OS X Yosemite

Tags: c++, c, xcode, gcc, openmp

```
$ gcc 12.c -fopenmp
12.c:9:9: fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found
#include<omp.h>
    ^
1 error generated.
```

While compiling openMP programs I get the above error. I am using OS X Yosemite. I first tried by installing native gcc compiler by typing gcc in terminal and later downloaded Xcode too still I got the same error. Then I downloaded gcc through:

```
$ brew install gcc
```

Still I'm getting the same error. I did try changing the compiler path too still it shows:

```
$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

So how do I compile programs with gcc?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26232432/since-gcc-on-mac-doesnt-support-openmp-what-can-i-do-to-let-it-support

Comment: I believe that Apple has removed gcc and that what appears to be gcc is a a link back to clang. So you have a few options 1) install gcc yourself 2) install the experimental clang with OpenMP support. Google should be your friend in either case.

Comment: As fas as installing gcc was concern it did no good.. It showed the same error `<omp.h>` not found where as a simple `Hello World!!!` did execute. Will try clang now, bit reluctant though because of its large size..

Comment: and nope same error.. `<omp.h> not found`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [<omp.h> library isn't found in the GCC version (4.2.1) in Mavericks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340117/omp-h-library-isnt-found-in-the-gcc-version-4-2-1-in-mavericks)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**EDIT:** As of [13 Aug 2017](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/16751) the `--without-multilib` option is no longer present in Homebrew and should not be used. The standard installation

```
brew install gcc
```

will provide a `gcc` installation that can be used to compile OpenMP programs. As below it will be installed into `/usr/local/bin` as `gcc-<version>`. The current gcc version available from Homebrew (as of writing) will install as `gcc-8`. You can compile programs with OpenMP support using it via

```
gcc-8 -fopenmp hello.c
```

Alternatively you could put an alias in your `.bashrc`file as

```
alias gcc='gcc-8'
```

and then compile using

```
gcc -fopenmp hello.c
```

---

**Note**: I'm leaving the original post here in case it is useful to somebody.

The standard gcc available on OS X through XCode and Clang doesn't support OpenMP. To install the Homebrew version of gcc with OpenMP support you need to install it with

```
brew install gcc --without-multilib
```

or as pointed out by @[Mark Setchell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836621/mark-setchell)

```
brew reinstall gcc --without-multilib
```

This will install it to the `/usr/local/bin` directory. Homebrew will install it as `gcc-<version>` so as not to clobber the gcc bundled with XCode.

Comment: I think Kavanai4 meant, `brew install gcc --without-multilib`

Comment: What does the `--without-multilib` flag mean?

Comment: @cullub It's used to build `gcc` without support for both 32 and 64 bit systems. It is a requirement with Homebrew to add OpenMP support.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `--without-multilib` flag is no longer required. I used OpenMP in January of this year and do not remember using this flag. Can anyone verify this?

Comment: @Jason I was getting errors compiling C++ code with OpenMP until I `brew upgrade`'d my gcc to gcc-7.1. Everything works fine now with `g++-7 hello.cpp -fopenmp`, and I didn't have use the `--without-multilib` flag.

Comment: Running `brew reinstall gcc --without-multilib` now gives `Warning: gcc: this formula has no --without-multilib option so it will be ignored!`

Answer (score 2):

I finally did some research and I finally came across a solution here: [<omp.h> library isn't found in the GCC version (4.2.1) in Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340117/omp-h-library-isnt-found-in-the-gcc-version-4-2-1-in-mavericks).

1. I got a new gcc complier from http://hpc.sourceforge.net/
2. Then I placed a new executable folder by 
   `$ sudo tar -xvf gcc-4.9-bin.tar -C /`
3. Later I switched to it by 
   `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` that seemed to do the trick!

Comment: You only need to do step 3, as you have already installed GCC from Homebrew. However, the default installation has a bug. Kavanai4's answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The question is 8 years old, but I'm writing this down for new users like me who encountered the same error.
workaround is to give the location of the omp.h file instead of #include <omp.h>.

#include "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libomp/17.0.5/include/omp.h"

you can include the location omp.h in your pc.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Isn't /opt a hard link to /Volumes/Macontosh HD/opt? And can't you configure the build to pass the appropriate -I rather than using an absolute path?

Comment: Thanks, Paul for your suggestion. I'm running Sonoma 14.1.1 and M2 chip. Tried all the workarounds suggested online and the only thing that worked was giving the absolute path that seemed to recognize the omp.h without giving an error.