# Using OpenMP with C++11 on Mac OS

Tags: c++, c++11, openmp, macos-sierra

I am trying to use some OpenMP multithreading features in my C++11 code like:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
```

When I try to compile using:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -fopenmp main.cpp -o main.o
```

I get the below error:

```
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
```

I alternatively tried compiling using:

```
g++ -fopenmp main.cpp -o main.o
```

But this gives the exact same error.

Would appreciate very much if you could advise how can I compile C++11 code that has OpenMP features on Mac OS 10.12. The other questions on posts here and elsewhere explain compiling C code for OpenMP, however, I couldn't find anything for C++11.

I get an error when I try to install libiomp, I get errors:

```
$ brew install libiomp
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Updated Formulae
ansible-cmdb        djview4             khard               oysttyer            shyaml              yazpp             
asciinema2gif       doctl               macvim              pazpar2             vala                you-get           
avro-c              elixir              mailhog             python              vdirsyncer          youtube-dl        
bash-git-prompt     file-roller         meson               python3             vim               
commandbox          glib                metaproxy           rtv                 x265              
consul-backinator   gtkextra            offlineimap         s-search            xonsh             

Error: Could not link:
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew

Please delete these paths and run `brew update`.
Error: Could not link:
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1

Please delete these paths and run `brew update`.
Error: No available formula with the name "libiomp" 
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

If I run using g++-6, based on Mark Setchell's post below, it works fine, thanks, I however get the below warnings, would appreciate any suggestions on how to avoid these:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/g++-6 -std=c++11 -fopenmp main.cpp -o main.o
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:4:11: warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:4:11: note: change section name to "__text"
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:89:11: warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:89:11: note: change section name to "__text"
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:551:11: warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:551:11: note: change section name to "__text"
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:1432:11: warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:1432:11: note: change section name to "__text"
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:1799:11: warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:1799:11: note: change section name to "__text"
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:1995:11: warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:1995:11: note: change section name to "__text"
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:2033:11: warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:2033:11: note: change section name to "__text"
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:2425:11: warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:2425:11: note: change section name to "__text"
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:2559:11: warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:2559:11: note: change section name to "__text"
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:2597:11: warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:2597:11: note: change section name to "__text"
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:2672:11: warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:2672:11: note: change section name to "__text"
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:2837:11: warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:2837:11: note: change section name to "__text"
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:2962:11: warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:2962:11: note: change section name to "__text"
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:3139:11: warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:3139:11: note: change section name to "__text"
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:3442:11: warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:3442:11: note: change section name to "__text"
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:3588:11: warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:3588:11: note: change section name to "__text"
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:3630:11: warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:3630:11: note: change section name to "__text"
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:5253:11: warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:5253:11: note: change section name to "__text"
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:5452:11: warning: section "__textcoal_nt" is deprecated
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/folders/jr/30r6h4cj4tl48q_cg9bt5f5h0000gn/T//ccq73Zfg.s:5452:11: note: change section name to "__text"
        .section __TEXT,__textcoal_nt,coalesced,pure_instructions
                 ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

Since my original answer below, the situation has improved and you can easily use OpenMP with the `clang++` compiler - hurraaaay!

To do that, first use **homebrew** to install `brew install libomp`:

```
brew install libomp
```

Then when using `clang++`, use these flags:

```
clang++ -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp main.cpp -o main -lomp
```

**Original Answer**

If you want to compile C++11 OpenMP code on OSX, the easiest way is to use `gcc` which you can install via `homebrew`.

First, check the available options:

```
brew options gcc
```

**Sample Output**

```
--with-all-languages
    Enable all compilers and languages, except Ada
--with-java
    Build the gcj compiler
--with-jit
    Build the jit compiler
--with-nls
    Build with native language support (localization)
--without-fortran
    Build without the gfortran compiler
--without-multilib
    Build without multilib support
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
```

So, I suspect you want:

```
brew install gcc --without-multilib --without-fortran
```

Once you have got it installed, you need to make sure you are using the `homebrew` version rather than the one Apple supplies. You need to know that `homebrew` installs everything in `/usr/local/bin` and that the C++ compiler is `g++-6`. So, you either need to compile with:

```
/usr/local/bin/g++-6 -std=c++11 -fopenmp main.cpp -o main
```

or, set up your PATH in your login profile:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

then you can just do:

```
g++-6 -std=c++11 -fopenmp ...
```

Note that if you choose the second option above (i.e. the `export PATH=...` option), you will either need to also type the `export` command in your current session once to activate it, or log out and log back in since your profile commands are only executed on login.

AFAIK, there is no need to explicitly install `libiomp` - not sure why you did that.

Comment: Mark, thanks! that worked well. I do get some warnings, that I posted above, could you please advise on those as well.

Comment: I guess it is some cruft associated with your previous, unsuccessful attempts as I have never seen it. I would try `brew rm libiomp --force` and rebuild your code and try again. If that fails, I would try `brew rm gcc --force` then install `gcc` again as per my answer above.

Comment: Thanks, Mark, will do.

Comment: The current options given by `brew options gcc` don't include `--without-multilib` or `--without-fortran`

Comment: @OmarHaque Thank you for pointing that out - I have made an update to my answer.

Comment: open ~/.bash_profile on macosx and write down 
export PATH="~/usr/local/bin:$PATH", this way it will be saved permanently.
g++-8 urfile.cpp -fopenmp

Comment: `-lomp` solved "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" error in my case

Answer (score 3):

The Clang that comes with XCode doesn't support OpenMP, however the one from llvm.org does. There are [instructions for how to install it](https://gist.github.com/fyears/59e67cf0f521bc199235).

By default on OSX, GCC is just a symlink to Clang (according to commentary on [Compile OpenMP programs with gcc compiler on OS X Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29057437/compile-openmp-programs-with-gcc-compiler-on-os-x-yosemite)). You can install the real GCC from Homebrew which definitely supports OpenMP.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I updated my original post with errors I get when trying to install libiomp.

Comment: You shouldn't need to install libiomp explicitly any longer. Indeed, the fact that you are calling it libiomp shows that you are using an old release, since in the latest LLVM releases (where OpenMP is enabled by default) the library is libomp.