# clang: "omp_set_num_threads" fail

Tags: c++, multithreading, clang, openmp

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    omp_set_num_threads(4);

#pragma omp parallel
    printf("Hello World\n");
}
```

> $ clang-omp++ openmp.cpp

I get

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_omp_set_num_threads",
>
> referenced from:
>         _main in openmp-7ace00.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang-3.5: error: linker command failed with exit
>
> code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Program compiles after `omp_set_num_threads(4);` removed.

> $ clang -v
>
> clang version 3.8.0 (http://llvm.org/git/clang.git
>
> 68170291648f0112957a8b3d6912a1a1fed81965) (http://llvm.org/git/llvm.git 92ca4a0cd38e8f17e62ecf6e93a44c8ecf098b12)
>
> Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0
>
> Thread model: posix

How do I set OpenMP thread number?

Comment: Do you compile with -fopenmp?

Comment: @Trevir No, I compile with `clang-omp++`, `-fopenmp` doesn't work for me.

Comment: -> clang-3.5: error, this clang version doesn't support openmp. Maybe something is wrong with your libraries

Comment: Have a look here... http://stackoverflow.com/a/39983933/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell No, that's not my case.

Comment: @Trevir Is it about retrieving clang from HomeBrew?

Comment: If you are compiling without -fopenmp then the OpenMP pragmas will be ignored and the OpenMP runtime won't be added to link command (hence the lack of a definition for omp_set_num_threads). So, your comment at 2 is the critical one. You need to fix your system so that -fopenmp does work!