# apple clang -fopenmp not working

Tags: clang, openmp

I am trying to use openmp with Apple clang but can't make it work. I did download and compile the openmp library from llvm. My problem is that clang doesn't recognize the `-fopenmp` flag. I get the following error:

```
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
```

I have version 8 of Xcode and clang. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have a look here... http://stackoverflow.com/a/39983933/2836621

Comment: Thanks. I know how to use openmp with gcc. My question is about using openmp specifically with clang.

Comment: Or this maybe... https://gist.github.com/fyears/59e67cf0f521bc199235

Comment: what version of clang are you using?  I don't know what xcode 8 has.  I can tell you that clang 3.9 supports it using the prebuilt binaries here: http://llvm.org/releases/download.html   so does my system clang: zacs-MacBook-Pro:test_blp xaxxon$ /usr/bin/clang -fopenmp
clang: error: no input files
zacs-MacBook-Pro:test_blp xaxxon$ ls -l /usr/bin/clang
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  18176 Jul  8 20:03 /usr/bin/clang

Comment: There are many questions about OpenMP and Clang here, just search http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clang+openmp?sort=votes&pageSize=50 . Older versions of clang don't support OpenMP. Clearly, your version does not support it, it explicitly says so in the message. Find a version which does.

Comment: FYI, re. several of the answers: homebrew no longer supports `clang-omp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I learned so far is that clang that comes with xcode does not support openmp. Also, the versions are different. So clang that comes with xcode 8 has version 8...

The best solution I have found so far is to install clang using homebrew: `brew install llvm --with-clang`. Right now I got version 3.9.0 and it does support openmp, so it solves my problem.

Comment: Warning from Homebrew for the command you provided:

    **llvm: this formula has no --with-clang option so it will be ignored!**

Comment: @glihm, The homebrew llvm removed the clang option in favor of including it by default. So now if you just do `brew install llvm` you should get the clang and clang++ compilers. However, it looks like lldb has recently been completely removed, so if you want lldb support, you will have to get it from somewhere else. Perhaps the answer should be updated?

Answer (score 11):

There is a way to use OpenMP with just Apple Clang. I learnt it while hacking a formula in Homebrew. You need libomp from Homebrew (`brew install libomp`), and then a different command-line option.

If you originally want to use `clang -fopenmp test.c`, with Apple Clang you need to use this alternative command:

```
clang -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp test.c -lomp
```