# can't complie using gcc with -fopenmp in OS X

Tags: gcc, terminal, openmp

I just started learning OpenMP. I tried to compile a simple Hello World C code using gcc.

Here's is my command line .

```
gcc -fopenmp HelloWorld.c
```

and this is my simple HelloWorld code .

```
#include<omp.h>
int main()
{
 #pragma omp parallel
 {
 int ID = 0;
 Printf(“hello(%d)”,ID);
 printf(“world(%d)”,ID);
 }
}
```

and when i try to compile in OS X. It showed the following error .

```
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
```

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39983933/2836621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after installing gcc through Homebrew

Install Homebrew

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Install gcc

```
brew install gcc
```

and code compiled after using this command line.

```
gcc-7 -fopenmp HelloWorld.c
```