# Xcode: Undefined symbol: _omp_get_max_threads

Tags: c, xcode, openmp, linker-errors

I'm trying to use openMP in C with Xcode 11.4. I have installed libomp with Homebrew, and homebrew apparently installed it in: /usr/local/Cellar/libomp/10.0.0/

The code below generates a linker error: Undefined symbol: _omp_get_max_threads (likewise for get_thread_num).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "/usr/local/Cellar/libomp/10.0.0/include/omp.h"

int main () {
#pragma omp parallel
{
int threadNum = omp_get_thread_num ();
int maxThreads = omp_get_max_threads(); 
}
return 0; }
```

I tried adding usr/local/Cellar to the Header Search Paths, and including omp.h directly in my Xcode project, and adding compilation flag `-openmp`, behavior does not change.

1) I coulnd't find a way to install OpenMP through Xcode directly, would it be possible / preferable?

2) Do I need to do something further for Xcode to recognize a library installed with Homebrew?

3) Why did Homebrew install the library in usr/local/Cellar, is that a bad sign?

4) Why is the missing symbol `_omp_get_max_threads` and not `omp_get_max_threads`?

(edit): There is also under usr/local/include the same three headers, omp.h, ompt.h and omp-tools.h, as in /usr/local/Cellar/libomp/10.0.0/. Not sure why.

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61871393/1374437) on how to use OpenMP with Apple's Clang compiler. Ignore that it shows `g++` in the commands - that's still Apple's Clang. The files in `/usr/local/include` are symlinks to the files in `/usr/local/Cellar/libomp/10.0.0/`. They are there because `/usr/local/include` is usually on the compiler's include path.

Comment: Thank you. From a terminal, `gcc -Xclang -fopenmp main.c -lomp` does work (this is C, not C++). However I am confused as to what to do within Xcode: under `Build phases -> compile sources -> flags` I have added `-Xclang -fopenmp -lomp`, but I get a third error: `Undefined symbol: ___kmpc_fork_call`. Using as flags: `gcc -Xclang -fopenmp main.c -lomp` does not work. I see `Link Binary with Libraries`, but `lopm` is not among the options.

Comment: No, no, no, don't involve GCC. Just the regular Clang compiler. You need to put `-Xclang -fopenmp` in the compiler options and `-lomp` in the linker options. I don't have Xcode right now, just the command line tools, so I can't tell you exactly where to put them. I'll install it later and see.

Comment: But g++ gives me a warning that I'm compiling C with a C++ compiler? Thank you for that, there is a field called `Other Linker Flags` under `Buid Settings`, but adding `-lomp` there (with only `-Xclang -fopenmp` in the compiler options) produces an error: `ld: library not found for -lomp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need to do to make a C or C++ project compile and link with OpenMP support in Xcode. Go to **Build Settings** in the project editor, select the project node and then the `All` settings filter. Make the following changes:

- **Header Search Paths** (in the **Search Paths** group) - set to (or add tp the existing value) `/usr/local/include`, so that the compiler can find `/usr/local/include/omp.h`
- **Library Search Paths** (in the **Search Paths** group) - set to (or add to the existing value) `/usr/local/lib`, so that the linker can find `/usr/local/lib/libomp.dylib`

Select the target executable node and make the following additional changes:

- **Other C Flags** (in the **Apple Clang - Custom Compiler Flags** group) - set to (or add) `-Xclang -fopenmp` to enable processing of OpenMP pragmas by the compiler
- **Other Linker Flags** (in the **Linking** group) - set to (or add) `-lomp` to enable linking with the OpenMP runtime library `libomp.dylib`

You can also make all four changes in the project node to make them project-wide or in the target node, depending on your project structure.

With C++ projects, one has to put `-Xclang -fopenmp` in **Other C++ Flags**.

Comment: Let's hope Apple are going to make it easier to use OpenMP in future Xcode versions now that LLVM and Clang fully support it.