# I am trying to install paprika on Mac OS

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, openmp

I am trying to download Paprica onto my Mac, https://www.polarmicrobes.org/installing-paprica-on-mac-osx/

The steps that I have completed are listed below

1. Install Python modules

   ```
    pip3 install numpy
    pip3 install biopython
    pip3 install joblib
    pip3 install pandas
    pip3 install seqmagick
   ```
2. Show import modules in python3 shell

   ```
    import numpy
    import Bio
    import joblib
    import pandas
   ```
3. Demonstrate that seqmagick works

   ```
    seqmagick
   ```
4. Using homebrew installed:

   ```
    brew install wget
   ```
5. Installed Infernal, placer, and epa-ng

   ```
   wget http://eddylab.org/infernal/infernal-1.1.1-macosx-intel.tar.gz
   tar -xzvf infernal-1.1.1-macosx-intel.tar.gz
   mv infernal-1.1.1-macosx-intel infernal
   ```
6. Then I installed gappa

   ```
   git clone --recursive https://github.com/lczech/gappa.git
   cd gappa
   make
   cd ~
   ```

This is where things stop working. When I run *make* in the gappa directory I get the output listed below. I have tried several different methods for getting OpenMP to work, but have not had any success. Any help that folks could give would be highly appreciated! :)

```
`(base) Gabriels-MacBook-Air:gappa gabrielprice$ make
Running CMake...
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:26 (cmake_minimum_required):
Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
CMake.

Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 11.0.0.11000033
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Gappa build type: RELEASE
-- Static linking of system libraries: OFF
CMake Deprecation Warning at libs/genesis/CMakeLists.txt:28 (cmake_minimum_required):
Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
CMake.

Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


-- Configuring Genesis
-- CMake version 3.19.3
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 11.0.0.11000033
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Genesis version: v0.24.0
-- Building Genesis as a dependency
-- Build type: RELEASE
-- Unity build: FULL
-- C++ compiler: AppleClang 11.0.0.11000033 at /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++
-- C compiler  : AppleClang 11.0.0.11000033 at /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of unsigned short
-- Check size of unsigned short - done
-- Searching 16 bit integer - Using unsigned short
-- Check if the system is big endian - little endian
-- Looking for zlib
-- Found ZLIB: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/lib/libz.tbd (found version "1.2.11") 
-- Found zlib: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/include 1.2.11
-- Using zlib
-- Looking for Threads
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found Threads: 
-- Using Threads
-- Looking for OpenMP
-- Using find_package( OpenMP ) patch
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [ ]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [-fopenmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [-fopenmp=libiomp5]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [-fopenmp=libomp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [-Xpreprocessor -fopenmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [-Xclang -fopenmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [/openmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [-Qopenmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [-openmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED

CMake Warning (dev) at     /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.19.3/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:426     (message):
  The package name passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args` (OpenMP)
  does not match the name of the calling package (OpenMP_patch).  This can
  lead to problems in calling code that expects `find_package` result
  variables (e.g., `_FOUND`) to follow a certain pattern.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  libs/genesis/tools/cmake/FindOpenMP_patch.cmake:384 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  libs/genesis/CMakeLists.txt:332 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Could NOT find OpenMP (missing: OpenMP_C_FLAGS OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS) 
-- Found OpenMP_C: -Xclang -fopenmp (found version "3.1") 
-- Found OpenMP_CXX: -Xclang -fopenmp (found version "3.1") 
-- Found OpenMP: TRUE (found version "3.1")  
-- Found OpenMP: -Xclang -fopenmp
-- Using OpenMP
-- Building static lib
-- Final build flags:
-- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS         :  -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pedantic -    pedantic-errors -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pedantic -pedantic-errors -Xclang     -fopenmp 
-- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE :  -O2 -DNDEBUG -O2 -DNDEBUG 
-- GENESIS_CXX_FLAGS       :  -Xclang -fopenmp 
-- GENESIS_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS:  
-- GENESIS_LINK_LIBRARIES  :  
-- Finished configuring Genesis
-- CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS   
-- GENESIS_LINK_LIBRARIES     /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/lib/libz.tbd;genesis_lib_static
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/gabrielprice/gappa/build
Running make...
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -s -C build
Scanning dependencies of target genesis_lib_static
[  2%] Building CXX object     libs/genesis/lib/genesis/CMakeFiles/genesis_lib_static.dir/__/__/__/__/genesis_unity_sources/lib   /all.cpp.o
/Users/gabrielprice/gappa/build/genesis_unity_sources/lib/all.cpp:172:13: fatal error:     'omp.h' file not found
#   include <omp.h>
            ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[3]: ***         [libs/genesis/lib/genesis/CMakeFiles/genesis_lib_static.dir/__/__/__/__/genesis_unity_sources/li.   b/all.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [libs/genesis/lib/genesis/CMakeFiles/genesis_lib_static.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

Comment: It looks like you didn't actually install infernal. You just unpacked the code and moved it. The documentation (http://eddylab.org/infernal/Userguide.pdf) says you still need to run `.configure` and `make`. Or just install it through homebrew since you used it for other packages. You are also clearly missing OpenMP.

Comment: You are using Clang from Apple's Xcode collection. It supports OpenMP but does not provide the runtime library and its header file. That can be fixed by installing `libomp` from Homebrew - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61871393/1374437). You need to add `-lomp` to the link flags. Alternatively, install GCC from Homebrew and use it to compile the code.