# omp.h' file not found while compiling source code

Tags: macos, clang, openmp

I am trying to compile this this source code (https://sites.google.com/site/bgcsoftware/) on a mac. I installed both hdf5 and gsl using homebrew.

Would you know what the problem might be?

Thank you in advance!

```
h5c++ -Wall -O2 -o bgc bgc_main.C bgc_func_readdata.C bgc_func_initialize.C bgc_func_mcmc.C bgc_func_write.C bgc_func_linkage.C bgc_func_ngs.C bgc_func_hdf5.C mvrandist.c -lgsl -lm
```

```
clang: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
bgc_main.C:17:10: fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found
#include <omp.h>
         ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
bgc_func_mcmc.C:12:10: fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found
#include <omp.h>
         ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You probably need to provide the folder containing `omp.h` as include folder to your compiler. For GCC this is done via `-I <folder>` option. For `h5c++` you need to consult the manual. BTW. If you compile your code as C++, please don't add C language tag. They are different languages.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like clang is the actual compiler being used. When compiling OpenMP with clang you need to pass the `-fopenmp` flag.

Try adding the `-fopenmp` flag like this:

```
h5c++ -fopenmp -Wall -O2 -o bgc \
  bgc_main.C bgc_func_readdata.C bgc_func_initialize.C \
  bgc_func_mcmc.C bgc_func_write.C bgc_func_linkage.C \
  bgc_func_ngs.C bgc_func_hdf5.C mvrandist.c -lgsl -lm
```

The `-fopenmp` flag tells the compiler replace the code marked with `#pragma omp ...` with generated parallel code and should automatically add the correct `-I` include flags behind the scenes.

You should be able to run

```
h5c++ --help | grep openmp
```

To see other openmp related flags, depending on your compiler/OS.

Comment: If the clang here is the one from Xcode, it pretends no to understand OpenMP, but you may be ab,e to trick it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61843134/running-openmp-with-different-version-of-g-in-mac

Answer (score 1):

adding -fopenmp did not help. However, the original code did run when I installed:
`brew install --build-from-source libomp`