# OpenMP's symbols not found?

Tags: openmp, macos-catalina, undefined-symbol

I have a problem about a **make** to install a software called ‘URANIE’, which is a scientific computing platform. By the way, I am on **macOS Catalina 10.15.4.**

When I did the make, here is what the terminal said :

```
*[ 64%] Linking CXX shared library libUranieModeler.so
ld: warning: -L path '/usr/lib/libxml2.dylib' is not a directory
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___kmpc_for_static_fini", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined. in TkNN.cxx.o
      _.omp_outlined..36 in TkNN.cxx.o
      _.omp_outlined..49 in TkNN.cxx.o
  "___kmpc_for_static_init_4", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined. in TkNN.cxx.o
      _.omp_outlined..36 in TkNN.cxx.o
      _.omp_outlined..49 in TkNN.cxx.o
  "___kmpc_fork_call", referenced from:
      URANIE::Modeler::TkNN::estimate_cpu(char const*) in TkNN.cxx.o
      URANIE::Modeler::TkNN::LSort(int, double*, int*, int) in TkNN.cxx.o
  "___kmpc_global_thread_num", referenced from:
      _.omp_outlined. in TkNN.cxx.o
      _.omp_outlined..36 in TkNN.cxx.o
      _.omp_outlined..49 in TkNN.cxx.o
  "_omp_set_num_threads", referenced from:
      URANIE::Modeler::TkNN::estimate_cpu(char const*) in TkNN.cxx.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [meTIER/modeler/souRCE/libUranieModeler.4.3.0.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [meTIER/modeler/souRCE/CMakeFiles/UranieModeler.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2*
```

My computer skills are limited so I don't really understand this error. I already did some research about it, but did not find any solution to my issue. I only understood that these symbols that aren’t found have a connection with OpenMP, if I am not mistaken. I installed **open-mpi** with brew and **libopenmpt** too. I also checked if open-mpi was well linked and it's the case, but I don't know if this information can help.

If someone can help me about this problem or can give me some advice to understand this error, I would appreciate it a lot.
If you need further information don't hesitate to reach me,, thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be useful to see if you can write and compile code that uses omp_set_num_threads(). If that works, then the problem is probably related to Uranie rather than OpenMP.

Comment: I'm also not a Mac user, but this may be useful to check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39979836/using-openmp-with-c11-on-mac-os/39983933#39983933