# OS X: installed gcc links to clang

Tags: macos, gcc, g++, homebrew

I already have `gcc` and `g++` install:

```
$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc

$ which g++
/usr/bin/g++

$ brew install gcc
Warning: gcc-6.2.0 already installed
```

I follow [Compile OpenMP programs with gcc compiler on OS X Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29057437/compile-openmp-programs-with-gcc-compiler-on-os-x-yosemite) to reinstall `gcc` via HomeBrew:

```
$ brew reinstall gcc --without-multilib
```

then

```
$ /usr/bin/g++ openmp.cpp
openmp.cpp:12:10: fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found
#include <omp.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

with `-fopenmp`

```
$ /usr/bin/g++ openmp.cpp -fopenmp
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
```

What's happening with this redirection? How could I use `gcc`/`g++`?

---

Though involved, it's not about `OpenMP`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`brew` installs tools in `/usr/local/bin`. Use `/usr/local/bin/g++6`:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/g++-6 --version
g++-6 (Homebrew gcc 6.2.0) 6.2.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Yes you were right. Upgrading gcc fixed it and I am getting similar errors in both.