# How to resolve `clang: error: unsupported option '-fsanitize=leak'` on apple devices

Tags: c++, clang

I am trying to run a simple leak check program.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   
    double *ptr = new double(3.14);


}
```

using the command
 `g++ -g -fsanitize=leak -o main main.cpp`

and I get the following error:

`clang: error: unsupported option '-fsanitize=leak' for target 'x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0'`

I stopped using the clang that comes with Xcode and installed clang/LLVM using homebrew.

```
$ which clang++
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++
```

```
clang++ --version
clang version 11.0.0
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin
```

EDIT: When I was using apple clang, g++ used to default to clang++. Apparently that changed when I installed llvm/clang. Thanks to @cigien  for pointing it out. g++ still uses default to the compiler that that comes with Apple clang.

```
 g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: You're showing `which clang++`, but compiling with `g++`. Are they aliases on your system?

Comment: When I was using apple clang,  g++ used to default to clang++. Apparently that changed when I installed llvm/clang. Thanks

Comment: System g++ is an alias for system clang++ on macs, but a weird one, as I believe it also uses and outdated Standard LIbrary. I recommend avoiding it at all costs.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but it's still unclear. If they're not aliases, then showing `which clang++` is meaningless if you're compiling with `g++`. Please clarify the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40034457/os-x-installed-gcc-links-to-clang) you should use:
`g++-10 -g -fsanitize=leak -o main main.cpp` (in this cases (with flag leak) there is no leak message for me `./main`, but it compile) then it should be:
`g++-10 -fsanitize=address -g main.cpp ; ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1 ./a.out` and it detect leak well.

- Note, that the correct path of brew installed g++ in MacOS is:

```
$ which g++-10
> /usr/local/bin/g++-10
--
$ which g++ 
> /usr/bin/g++ //this is pseudonym of clang
```

The same for gcc-10 (10 is my current version. You should use your version instead of that)

---

If you use `CMakeLists.txt` file you will configure it like this:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fsanitize=[sanitizer_name] [additional_options] [-g] [-OX]") 
# leak sanitizer_name not works for me. should be address
```

And should execute cmake command like this:
`cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/local/bin/gcc-10 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/local/bin/g++-10 ..`
And then `ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1 ./a.out`

Note, that if you open `*/CMakeFiles/3.18.4/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake` file you will observe the compiled info, and now it will be g++.