# Using Memory and Lead Sanitizer on macOS for C Programming

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
    int *m = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));

    m[0] = 1;
    m[1] = 2;
    m[5] = 3;

}
```

I want to be able to detect the memory leaks (as I am using `malloc` without using `free`. I was able to use `clang test.c -o test -fsanitize=address -g` but I am unable to use `-fsanitize=memory` or `-fsanitize=leak`. As I am getting the following error: `clang: error: unsupported option '-fsanitize=memory' for target 'arm64-apple-darwin21.2.0'` and `clang: error: unsupported option '-fsanitize=leak' for target 'arm64-apple-darwin21.2.0'`. I just wanted to know exactly what I have to do in order to use Memory Sanitizer and Leak Sanitizer on my macOS Monterey and be able to check that I just accessed memory that I should not have.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65112164/how-to-resolve-clang-error-unsupported-option-fsanitize-leak-on-apple-dev

Comment: `m[5] = 3;` is not a leak. A leak is when your program enters a state in which it will not free memory (prior to termination) that is no longer needed, as happens when you lose track of the address of allocated memory. Assigning `m = 0;` would be a leak since it would lose the value that was returned by `malloc`.

Comment: Well what I meant in my question was that I would be accessing memory that I had not allocated. I think that would mean I was creating a segmentation fault. I was wondering how I could check that I made a segmentation fault with the Memory Sanitizer and Leak Sanitizer...

Comment: You use address sanitizer and UB sanitizer for that (-fsanitize=address,undefined).

Comment: Ok, I was able to do that, but now going back to what @EricPostpischil stated, if I set m = 0, than that would cause a leak. So I was wondering how I could use -fsanitizie=memory or -fsanitize=leak if the need arises to do so... I am beginner so I think I am not being clear enough in the question I want answered. I am able to make the address sanitizer work, but I also want to work with the memory sanitizer and leak sanitizer, what are the steps and processes I need to follow in order to accomplish that?

Comment: A *leak* is when you allocate something and then lose access to the last pointer pointing to it. Your program has a leak regardless of whether you set `m` to null or not, because you lose access to it when it goes out of scope. Have you tried `-fsanitize=address`? This should detect leaks as well. [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WrnorPhKa) If this doesn't work for you, [ditch weird Apple's clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53456304/mac-os-leaks-sanitizer). Normal clang supports -fsanitize=memory too.

Comment: Another way to detect such errors is [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) The advantage is that you don't need any special compiler support. The disadvantage is that you need to install and use another piece of software.