# How do I install rpy2 when clang doesn't support OpenMP (Mac OSX)?

Tags: clang, llvm, openmp, llvm-clang, rpy2

I am trying to use pip to install rpy2 on OSX 10.12.5.  I get this error:

```
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

From what I understand, this is because my version of clang does not support OpenMP.  Using homebrew, I installed LLVM 8.1.0 (clang 802.0.42), but now I need to update clang to support OpenMP.  Can anyone give me detailed instructions of how to go about this?  I am not understanding the other sources I am reading online.

Comment: You can generally compile software that requires openmp on macs using homebrew gcc (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29109926/28035). It might help to show us how you're trying to install rpy2, including all the commands you've issued and all the output (I haven't had this issue and I run rpy2 on several macs...).

Comment: FWIW there is an open issue about it here: https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/403/cannot-pip-install-rpy2-with-latest-r-340

Answer (score 2):

I just got rpy2-2.9.0 to install via pip on Mac OSX 10.13, after getting the same error you reported, by downgrading to R 3.3.3, downloaded from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/. I just re-installed R 3.3.3 then re-ran 'pip install rpy2' and it installed fine.